# A 2D grid of 100 x 100 squares in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, 2d, opengl-es-2.0

I'd like to display a 2D grid of 100 x 100 squares. The size of each square is 10 pixels wide and filled with color. The color of any square may be updated at any time.

I'm new to OpenGL and wondered if I need to define the vertices for every square in the grid or is there another way? I want to use OpenGL directly rather than a framework like Cocos2D for this simple task.

Comment: An alternative approach might be to use a 100x100 texture and draw that into a single quad using a GL_NEAREST magnification filter. Assuming a square quad, this should give you squares of each pixel color. You could then update this texture (ideally, using the texture caches) to redefine the colors on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get away with just rendering the positions of your squares as points with a size of 10. GL_POINT's always are a set number of pixels wide and high, so that will keep your squares 10 pixels always. If you render the squares as a quad you will have to make sure they are the right distance from the camera to be 10 pixels wide and high (also the aspect may affect it).